# Rally Query to seperate similar looking tags e.g. Project N and Project Name

Tags: rally

I have a scenario where I have two Similar looking tags "Project N" and "Project Name". There is a custom grid (Defect) that has a query thats intended for "Project N" but also catches "Project Name" what is the best way to exclude "Project Name" when im looking for "Project N"

**Sample Query**

```
(((Requirement.Tags.Name contains "Project N") AND (State < "Closed")) AND (Tags.Name !contains "Project N"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a set of tags in a similar situation to test with, but it seems like if you change the !contains to "Name" it should get just the "Project N" tagged items, without getting the "Project Name" tagged items.

```
(((Requirement.Tags.Name contains "Project N") AND (State < "Closed")) AND (Tags.Name !contains "Project Name"))
```

That should find all of the items that are tagged as "Project N" and with a state less than closed, and which are not tagged with something with "Project Name". - However, if the items that are tagged with "Project N" are also tagged with "Project Name" or are also tagged another tags such as "Project Name - Condor", it will exclude those items. ... I am not sure there is a way to get around that with the custom grid; I think you would need to create a custom report to avoid that situation, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup the same set of tags and tested the same query string however I am not running into the same issue.  I tried:

```
(((Requirement.Tags.Name contains "Project N") AND (State < "Closed")) AND (Tags.Name !contains "Project N"))
```

My query is excluding the User Story with the 'Project Name' tag as desired.

If this is still not working for you I would suggest you open a case with Rally Support using the Contact Support link at the bottom of any page in Rally.